# How to fix: (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a system for a project that asks the user if they would like to create an account or sign in. I am having issues with the 'if' condition on line 5. The error message in its whole is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    if login_or_signup("signup"):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The code:

```
import uuid
import hashlib
login_or_signup = input("would you like to log in? Or signup?: ")

if login_or_signup("signup"):
  def hash_password(password):
      # uuid is used to generate a random number
      salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
      return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt

  def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
      password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
      return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

  new_pass = input('Please enter a password: ')
  hashed_password = hash_password(new_pass)
  old_pass = input('Now please enter the password again to check: ')
  if check_password(hashed_password, old_pass):
      print('The passwords match!')
  else:
      print('I am sorry but the password does not match')

else:
  print("(NOT CODED YET)")
```

Comment: What did you expect from `login_or_signup("signup")`?

Comment: If you want to compare two strings, but don't know how, then please [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/). Don't guess. And looking later in the code you *do* know how to compare values for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a minor error, as others have mentioned. You need to compare strings in the following manner inside an `if` statement:

```
if login_or_signup == "signup":
```